# How do I get next parameter in my .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current URL

```
http://domain.com/page/2/
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Next URL

```
http://domain.com/page/2/?by=1
```

How to get the `by=1`?

Because when I `print_r($_GET)` It's only display `Array ( [p] => 2 )`

What should I write in my .htacces to get the `[by] => 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the end of your line from `[L]` to `[QSA,L]` to preserve the query string.

Comment: Opss. Working now without white space. Thanks Michael